How can I choose an arithmetic operation based on user input?
I am trying to have the user input two numbers and an operator and then perform the chosen arithmetic operation:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a;
int b;
int c;
int operation;

int main()
{
    printf("Enter First number :- ");
    scanf("%d" , &a);
    printf("Enter Second Number :- ");
    scanf("%d" , &b);
    printf("Enter Operator :-");
    scanf("%d" , &c);

    #define DMAS c
    operation = (a DMAS b);
    printf("%d" , operation);
}

On the line operation = (a DMAS b); I am getting an error:

expected '(' before 'c'

Please guide me on where I went wrong, since I am new to programming.

In C and other statically compiled languages you can't construct an expression at runtime (like from the user provided numbers and operators in your case). You'll need to use a switch-case statement to calculate the results based on the operator.

You cannot do this with the preprocessor in C: (a DMAS b) expands at compile time to (a c b), which is a syntax error.
There is no easy way to construct C source expressions at runtime either, there is no eval function in C like in interpretive languages. You could construct the source code for another program, run the compiler and run the resulting program, but this is beyond the scope of your question and depends on the OS and set of tools available...
The classic solution to evaluate expressions entered at runtime is to test which operator is applied and and dispatch to the appropriate code.
Here is a simple example:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
    int result;

    printf("Enter First number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("Enter Second Number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &b) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("Enter Operator: ");
    if (scanf("%c", &c) != 1)
        return 1;

    switch (c) {
      case '+':
        result = a + b;
        break;
      case '-':
        result = a - b;
        break;
      case '*':
        result = a * b;
        break;
      case '/':
        result = a / b;
        break;
      case '%':
        result = a % b;
        break;
      case '|':
        result = a | b;
        break;
      case '&':
        result = a & b;
        break;
      case '^':
        result = a ^ b;
        break;
      default:
        printf("unsupported operator '%c'\n", c);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}


@tnavidi: you cannot add |! or &! as single character operators: these are not single characters. If the operator is input as a string, extra combinations can be handled, but it is beyond the scope of this simple question.

@arnold: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.
